# Change button background color by clicking a different button on a different page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to achieve a task that bugs me a bit. I have 2 buttons on 2 different pages, I want to achieve this; when pressing on the button situated on the second page, to change the background colour of the button situated on the first page. Example:
First Page:

```
<Stacklayout>
  <Button Text="Task 1"
          x:Name = "firstPage"
          BackgroundColor = "Red" />
</Stacklayout>
```

SecondPage:

```
<Stacklayout>
  <Button Text="Completed"
          x:Name = "secondPage"
          Clicked = "ChangeColourForFirst" />
</Stacklayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use **MessagingCenter** to send notification when clicking the button .

#### in the first page

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, Color>(this, "changeColor", (arg,color) => {

            firstPage.BackgroundColor = color;


        });

    }
```

#### in the second page

```
private void ChangeColourForFirst(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<Object, Color>(this, "changeColor", Color.Red); // send the bgcolor that you want to change
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas! It does the job for my Task, much appreciated!